# How do I pass arguments to dashboard widget callback functions?

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I'm struggling to use the $callback_args parameter of wp_add_dashboard_widget successfully.

The following code keeps displaying string(0)"" when dumping $args:

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'sample_widget_setup' );

function sample_widget_setup() {

    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        'sample_dashboard_widget',
        'Sample Widget',
        'sample_dashboard_widget_callback',
        null,
        'sample_string'
    );
}

function sample_dashboard_widget_callback($args) {
    var_dump($args);
}
```

How can I pass a variable to sample_dashboard_widget_callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The args are stored in the 2nd variable passed to your callback function.

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'sample_widget_setup' );

function sample_widget_setup() {

    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
      'sample_dashboard_widget',
      'Sample Widget',
      'sample_dashboard_widget_callback',
       null,
        'sample_string'
    );
}

function sample_dashboard_widget_callback( $var, $args ) {
    var_dump( $args );
}
```

Output from above:

```
array
  'id' => string 'sample_dashboard_widget' (length=23)
  'title' => string 'Sample Widget' (length=13)
  'callback' => string 'sample_dashboard_widget_callback' (length=32)
  'args' => string 'sample_string' (length=13)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!  Do you, by chance, know what the 1st variable is actually for?

Comment: from the codex; `wp_add_dashboard_widget($widget_id, $widget_name, $callback, $control_callback, $callback_args );`

Comment: `$control_callback`
(string) (optional) The name of a function you create that will handle submission of widget options (configuration) forms, and will also display the form elements.